# React iframe cross origin error despite being in same origin

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe

I have an IFrame in React which makes use of the `srcDoc` property to display the string HTML contents which is an email body (the ref being because `this` is null when the function is called):

```
const ref = useRef();
function onIframeLoad() {
    ref.current.height = ref.current.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
<iframe onLoad={onIframeLoad} ref={ref} style={{width: "100%"}} sandbox="" srcDoc={email.body} />
```

I am trying to make IFrame become the height of the contents of the IFrame, otherwise it is very short with a scrollbar, hence the `onIframeLoad` function. But for some reason the browser thinks I am trying to do a cross-origin access despite the frame and body being in the same origin:
[image: error]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. Turns out same origin access is not allowed by default (for some reason) so you have to enable it by specifying it in the sandbox parameter:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Next.js React and Nest.js stack, this solution helped me - add the following instructions to the next.config.js file

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/_next/:path*",
        headers: [
          { 
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "http://localhost:3000" 
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```